# Can't install laravel-echo-server with npm and .ebextensions (code ELIFECYCLE)

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, amazon-ec2

## Context of Error

I am launching an EC2 instance (Linux PHP platform). During the build, I install npm successfully as well as an unrelated package PM2.

However after that it tries to install laravel-echo-server using `npm i -g laravel-echo-server` and it always returns an error:

```
$ npm i -g laravel-echo-server


 /usr/bin/laravel-echo-server -> /usr/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/bin/server.js

  > spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/node_modules/spawn-sync
  > node postinstall

  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
  npm ERR! file sh
  npm ERR! path sh
  npm ERR! errno -2
  npm ERR! spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall: `node postinstall`
  npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

## Attempts at Resolving

The weird thing is it works completely fine when I SSH into the instance after build and run the command myself. It is only when the .ebextensions build tries to call it that it fails.

```
npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path true  #to make sure it has the right node path
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node        #to create a sym link to the node location
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs       #another attempt to create a sym link to the node location
```

## Additional Info

#### .ebextensions script

```
sudo yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo yum install -y nodejs
npm install -g pm2@latest
npm install -g laravel-echo-server
```

#### which node

```
/usr/bin/node
```

#### which nodejs

```
not found    #or /usr/bin/nodejs if I create the symlink, but that doesn't help
```

#### which pm2

```
/usr/bin/pm2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a problem with spawn sync, so I changed it to this and it worked succesfully:

```
npm i -g laravel-echo-server --ignore-scripts spawn-sync
```